# Unexpected Blue Screen on Windows Server 2012

Tags: windows-server-2012

We are starting to have random reboots of our Windows Server 2012 machine. Looking through the information we have, we found a BlueScreen event that correlates with the time of the reboot. Searching around for the BCCode 3b mentions driver problems, but our drivers seem to be working correctly. Does anyone have experience with this code and found a solution to it? Below are the details from the BlueScreen event.

> ```
> Problem Event Name: BlueScreen
> OS Version: 6.2.9200.2.0.0.272.7
> BCCode: 3b
> BCP1: 00000000C0000005
> BCP2: FFFFF96000220373
> BCP3: FFFFF8804EC84BA0
> BCP4: 0000000000000000
> OS Version: 6_2_9200
> Service Pack: 0_0
> Product: 272_3
> ```

Comment: `our drives seem to be working correctly` - except when they cause the server to BSOD. If the information points to a driver problem then I'd look at the drivers first and foremost.

Comment: Sorry, I meant to say drivers, not drives. I've fixed that in my question

Comment: I knew what you meant. If the error indicates that it might be a driver problem then that's what you should look at, whether you think it's a driver problem or not.

Answer (score 4):

There is not enough information supplied here to just be able to look at the stop code `3b` and say what the root cause of it is.

From https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff558949(v=vs.85).aspx

> The SYSTEM_SERVICE_EXCEPTION bug check has a value of 0x0000003B. This indicates that an exception happened while executing a routine that transitions from non-privileged code to privileged code.

Parmeter 1 is the exception. In your case, it is `00000000C0000005` which is "Access Denied". Who knows what this means for sure, but access denied errors are often caused by some function trying to read from or write to a null pointer (memory address 0), which is one of the most common software bugs ever.

Parameter 2 is the address of the instruction that caused the exception and parameter 3 is the context record.

Those memory addressees are not persistent across reboots, so they mean absolutely nothing without a memory dump.

Use [DumpConfigurator](http://winplattools.codeplex.com/releases/view/119856) to configure the machine for a **full** memory dump so that the next time this happens, you can use a debugger to investigate the root cause more thoroughly.

But once you have the **full** memory dump, be careful about who you share it with, because memory dumps often contain sensitive information such as passwords that were stored in memory at the time.

Comment: Thanks for the full explanation of the parameters too. I'll get a full memory dump next time and start examining it. Hopefully I'll be able to narrow down what is causing this and update.

Answer (score 2):

BSOD are often caused by damaged RAM modules. Is you RAM ECC or not?

Anyway, try running memtest86 for 1-2 hours (during low usage hours, eg: night) to ruling out DRAM issues.